# Is there a one line way I can find the length of the longest of two C# strings?

Tags: c#

I have two strings as input parameters to a method:

```
public List<AnswerRow> makeAnswers(string c, string r)
```

On the first line of my method I have the code to check for a condition where both are null and then do a return:

```
if (c == null && r == null)
{
    return null;
}
```

Is there a safe (one of the two might be null), one line way that I can find the length of the longest string?

Note the return type is used later on in the method after I know the length of the longest string.

Comment: Do you want the length or the string returned? Title says length but question says string.

Comment: Sorry to everyone I did not make the question clear. I would like the length of the longest string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the answer to that is in the question text: "Note the return type is used later on in the method after I know the length of the longest string."

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have to call you out on that unfortunately, your comment was posted after the question was edited. But whatever, oh well, nevermind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Math.Max(c==null?0:c.Length, r==null?0:r.Length)
```

Comment: That finds the length - not the string

Comment: @Ian the title says 'find the length of the longest of two strings'. There's ambiguity in the question, so doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: That is true, there is some ambiguity - I'd tend to go with a question over the title though. PS. I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: @Ian Fair enough, but I would tend to go with the question in the title over the body of the question, based on the assumption that most people will consider the title of the question more carefully than several paragraphs of text.

Answer (score 4):

```
int length = Math.Max((c??"").Length, (r??"").Length);
```

Comment: In the case where both have the same length. The length of either one would be fine. Can you explain the ?? operator. I have never seen that before.

Comment: The only downside of this, is you're potentially returning an empty string, rather than a null - which is not the same as the thing you were given.

Comment: @SamanthaJ: ?? returns the right hand side of the operator if the left side is null

Comment: The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: The return type is `List<AnswerRow>`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, the poster wants the string length.

Comment: @Tim, you're right, edtted...  but he just changed the quesiton, now he wants the length...